# Speed optimization with matix vector multiplication in Python

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy, matrix

I would like to optimize the following code in python:

```
for imode in N.arange(3*natom): #Loop on perturbation (6 for 2 atoms)
  for ikpt in N.arange(nkpt):
    for iband in N.arange(nband):    
      for iatom1 in N.arange(natom):
        for iatom2 in N.arange(natom):
          for idir1 in N.arange(0,3):
            for idir2 in N.arange(0,3):    
              fan_corrQ[imode,ikpt,iband] += EIG2D[ikpt,iband,idir1,iatom1,idir2,iatom2]*\
                  displ_red_FAN2[imode,iatom1,iatom2,idir1,idir2]
              ddw_corrQ[imode,ikpt,iband] += ddw_save[ikpt,iband,idir1,iatom1,idir2,iatom2]*\
                  displ_red_DDW2[imode,iatom1,iatom2,idir1,idir2]
```

As you can see I would like to make a sum over some indices of my multispace python array.
I would like to have something like:

```
for imode in N.arange(3*natom): #Loop on perturbation (6 for 2 atoms)
  for ikpt in N.arange(nkpt):
    for iband in N.arange(nband):
      fan_corrQ[imode,ikpt,iband] = N.dot(EIG2D[ikpt,iband,:,:,:,:],displ_red_FAN2.T[imode,:,:,:,:])
      ddw_corrQ[imode,ikpt,iband] = N.dot(ddw_save[ikpt,iband,:,:,:,:],displ_red_DDW2.T[imode,:,:,:,:])
```

Off course I have a problem of not multiplying the same indices so I have redefying it. I must also point out that I'm dealing with Complex number:

```
displ_red_DDW2 = N.zeros((3*natom,3,natom,3,natom),dtype=complex)
```

I have also try a small dummy program in ipython to test it:

```
import numpy as N
atom =2
displ_red_FAN2 = N.zeros((3*natom,3,natom,3,natom),dtype=complex)
EIG2D = N.zeros((216,12,3,2,3,2))
```

So I have that displ_red_FAN2.shape = (6, 3, 2, 3, 2) and  EIG2D.shape = (216, 12, 3, 2, 3, 2)

So if I do something like:

```
N.dot(EIG2D[1,1,:,:,:,:],displ_red_FAN2[1,:,:,:,:].T).shape
```

it should give (3,2,3,2) but instead it gives (3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3) ??? Then when the multiplication is done I guess that I will have to do some sort of sum to reduce the dimensionality.

Any help would be great !

Cheers!

Samuel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could massively simplify this by using Einstein summation ([`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)). The syntax can be a bit tricky to get your head around, so I've simplified the names of your variables and indices a bit:

```
# arrays
EIG2D           --> A
displ_red_FAN2  --> B
fan_corrQ       --> C

# indices
ikpt    --> i
iband   --> j
idir1   --> k
iatom1  --> l
idir2   --> m
iatom2  --> n
imode   --> o
```

`np.einsum` takes a comma-separated list of subscripts, each of which refers to 
a dimension of the corresponding input array. Whenever an index is repeated, it 
is summed in the output. You can also specify the order of summation in the 
output by giving the output indices as well.

In your case, I think that this:

```
...
fan_corrQ[imode,ikpt,iband] += EIG2D[ikpt,iband,idir1,iatom1,idir2,iatom2]*\
    displ_red_FAN2[imode,iatom1,iatom2,idir1,idir2]
...
```

should simplify to this:

```
C = np.einsum('ijklmn,olnkm->oij',A,B)
```

You should have a play around with this and make sure I haven't made any mistakes! As with `sgpc`'s answer, similar caveats apply in terms of memory requirements.

Comment: Sir, you made my day !!! It work perfectly and is much easier to understand for me (physicist). For information the code went from 40 sec to 5 sec going from the "for" loops to the einsum :)

Comment: glad to hear it - I only recently found out about `np.einsum` myself, and it has rocked my world ever since

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.tensordot()`

```
fan_corrQ = np.tensordot(displ_red_FAN2, EIG2D, axes = ([3,1,4,2],[2,3,4,5]))
ddw_corrQ = np.tensordot(displ_red_DDW2, ddw_save, axes = ([3,1,4,2],[2,3,4,5]))
```

This gives the same result than your current approach and it is about `9 times` faster.

About your other question. The `np.dot()` for a `ND-array` works [summing over the last axis of the first array and the second-to-last axis of the second array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help,
I don't think you need to swap the axes.
  fan_corrQ = displ_red_FAN2.dot(EIG2D) 
# [3*natom,natom,natom,idir1,nkpt,nband,idir1,iatom1,iatom2]
  fan_corrQ = N.sum(fan_corrQ,axis=8)
  fan_corrQ = N.sum(fan_corrQ,axis=7)
  fan_corrQ = N.sum(fan_corrQ,axis=6)
  fan_corrQ = N.sum(fan_corrQ,axis=3)
  fan_corrQ = N.sum(fan_corrQ,axis=2)
  fan_corrQ = N.sum(fan_corrQ,axis=1)
Seems to work. BUT it does not give the same result as previously. We want to make the multiplication for all the 4 dimension we want to reduce.

Comment: I hope this works... if it doesn't, there is surely a way to do what you want without python for loops...

Comment: It now work from a dimensionaly point of view but not from a physical one :p
Maybe by making multiple dot product on every dimension we want?

Comment: @sponce I updated the answer. There is a `np.tensordot` than does the multiple `dot`...

Comment: @sgpc that's a damn good update to your answer. FYI @sponce: you should benchmark our two solutions - `np.tensordot` may potentially be slightly quicker in your case. That's because `np.einsum` is so general (e.g. variable number of input arrays) that it makes it harder to optimize the underlying calls to BLAS libraries.